# ReactNative Screen Background and header icon

Tags: react-native

I have background image like below

[image]

On top of the screen background image, I have to place icon at the center like below,

[image]

Vertical mode view
[image]

Full screen or horizontal mode
[image]

How can I place circle icon in the background image without clipping image in full screen. Because  in full screen the curve shaped image is not visible and icon appear in the middle of screen.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
<ImageBackground
  style={{flex: 1}}
  source={require('../../assets/images/test.png')}
  >
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Image
        source={require('../../assets/icons/app_icon.png')}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          marginTop: 100
        }}
      />
   
    <View style={styles.contentCenter}>
      
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        The Big Bang Theory
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    padding: 15,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',    
    textAlign: 'center',    
  },
  contentCenter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
   
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    padding: 10,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things here that can affect this

First of all, you haven't provided `resizeMode` to your `ImageBackground` that's probably why your curve is not showing up in full screen.

Second, You can use `position: 'absolute'` and then `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` property to position your image on top of `ImageBackground`. `zIndex` can also affect your View here

Comment: can you add a screenshot so that I get exactly what is happening?

Comment: updated image in question